# Command Handler's file reading doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so basically, I have followed a video (from IGP) on how to make a command handler for a bot. and I can't figure out why it doesn't work (Tomfoolery is the folder for commands)

```
client.commands = new Collection();
const commands = fs.readdirSync("./Tomfoolery/").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))
for(file of commands) {
    const commandName = file.split(".")[0]
    const command = require('./Tomfoolery/'+commandName)
    client.commands.set(commandName, command)
}
```

I tried `npm rebuild node-sass` and `npm rebuild node-sass --force` and similar stuff, and it still gives me:
`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './Tomfoolery/'` (even though Tomfoolery IS on the same folder as the bot.js file)

Comment: Why did you need `npm rebuild node-sass`?

Comment: I googled a solution before posting this question and that popped up

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are accessing the correct path and prepending the path with `__dirname` will fix the issue

```js
client.commands = new Collection();
const commands = fs.readdirSync(__dirname+"/Tomfoolery/").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))
for(file of commands) {
    const commandName = file.split(".")[0]
    const command = require(__dirname+'/Tomfoolery/'+commandName)
    client.commands.set(commandName, command)
}
```

Comment: it fixed the error BUT now I think my bot is stuck on doing something I don't know of, very weird. it's the exact same folder name as before, I'm sure of it.